# A set of partial limits which is closed under mean

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers s.t. if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then so is $\frac 1 2 (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. Prove that the set $A$ of partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an interval.

I know that if $(\lambda_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence of partial limits (elements of $A$), then its limit is also a partial limit. But I am not sure how to use this fact to show that the set $A$ contains every point between two given elements of it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_1 < L_2$ be partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $L_1 < \lambda < L_2$ be some real number. We shall construct by recursion a sequence of partial limits that converges to $\lambda$. We will do so by defining a sequence of intervals $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty=([u_n,v_n])_{n=1}^\infty$ with lengths descending to $0$.

Let $[u_1,v_1]=[L_1, L_2]$. If $\lambda$ resides in $[u_1, \frac{u_1+v_1}{2}]$, define $I_2=[u_2,v_2]$ to be this interval, and otherwise take it to be "the other half", $[\frac{u_1+v_1}{2},v_1]$. Note that both ends are partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Now, if we already defined $I_n=[u_n,v_n]$ s.t. $\lambda \in I_n $ and both ends are partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, take $I_{n+1}=[u_n, \frac{u_n+v_n}{2}]$ in case $\lambda \le \frac{u_n+v_n}{2}$, and  $I_{n+1}=[\frac{u_n+v_n}{2}, v_n]$ otherwise.

Notice that $I_n \subseteq I_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and that $\lim _{n \to \infty}(v_n-u_n)=0$. So, by Cantor's lemma, $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ both converge, and have the same limit. Since $\lambda\in I_n$ for all $n$, this limit must be $\lambda$, so we found a sequence of partial limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $\lambda$, as desired.